# Can the performance of this type-selection be improved?

Tags: ruby, performance

Assuming I get some data like `{ :type => 'X', :some_other_key => 'foo' }` on runtime and depending on some conditions I want to initialize the corresponding class for it. Our way to do this is like this.

```
TYPE_CLASSES = [
  TypeA,
  TypeB,
  TypeC,
  # ...
  TypeUnknown
]

TYPE_CLASSES.detect {|type| type.responsible_for?(data)}.new
```

We iterate over a list of classes and ask each one if it is responsible for the given data and initialize the first one found.

The order of the `TYPE_CLASSES` is important and some `responsible_for?` methods do not only check the type but also other keys inside of `data`. So some specialized class checking for `type == 'B' && some_other_key == 'foo'` has to come before a generalized class checking only for `type == 'B'`.

This works fine and is easily extensible, but `TYPE_CLASSES` list is already quite long, so in the worst case finding out the right type could result in iterating until the last element and calling for each type the `responsible_for?` check.

Is there any way to improve the performance and avoid iterating over each element while still preserving the order of the checks?

Comment: It might make more sense to initialize this at startup, no? E.g., have a map of types/responsibilities and have the responsible classes register themselves, or some other mechanism.

Comment: @DaveNewton We don't know what data we get at startup, in a request we get JSON via a REST API and depending of the content, we need to initialize the right class to process that data.

Comment: But you know which classes are responsible for which type. I'm saying instead of iterating over a crap-ton of classes for every request, register the handlers at the beginning so it's an O(1) lookup later.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you. Can you maybe add some code demonstrating what you mean?

Comment: Not without knowing what `responsible_for?` does. The nutshell is that you have logic that knows how to decide what class is responsible for what data. I'm saying try to figure out a way to encapsulate that knowledge in a way that allows a direct mapping between that and the responsible classes. Whether or not that's possible, I'm not sure--depends.

Comment: @DaveNewton if it were only about checking the type key, it would easily work with just a Hash mapping the type key to the corresponding class. But since there are multiple classes that have the same type key and the right class depends on other fields, I don't know how to model this to get a direct mapping.

Comment: Well, you'd get somewhat better performance by having running a check based on key then a check based on fields. You could create a composite key based on an ordered string concatenation. Have you even identified that this is a performance issue? It still depends on what you're making the decision on, and we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If matching the data set to classes is as complex as you described it, it might make sense to use decision tree building algorithms ([example](http://www.saedsayad.com/decision_tree.htm)).

You can use [AI4R library](http://www.ai4r.org/machineLearning.html) to do that in Ruby.

Probably you don't need to build that tree dynamically. So you can just use the library to basically generate optimized detection strategy for you, example from the documentation:

```
DATA_LABELS = [ 'city', 'age_range', 'gender', 'marketing_target'  ]
DATA_SET = [  
   ['New York',  '<30',      'M',  'Y'],
         ['Chicago',   '<30',      'M',  'Y'],
         ['Chicago',   '<30',      'F',  'Y'],
         ['New York',  '<30',      'M',  'Y'],
         ['New York',  '<30',      'M',  'Y'],
         ['Chicago',   '[30-50)',  'M',  'Y'],
         ['New York',  '[30-50)',  'F',  'N'],
         ['Chicago',   '[30-50)',  'F',  'Y'],
         ['New York',  '[30-50)',  'F',  'N'],
         ['Chicago',   '[50-80]',  'M',  'N'],
         ['New York',  '[50-80]',  'F',  'N'],
         ['New York',  '[50-80]',  'M',  'N'],
         ['Chicago',   '[50-80]',  'M',  'N'],
         ['New York',  '[50-80]',  'F',  'N'],
         ['Chicago',   '>80',      'F',  'Y']
       ]
id3 = ID3.new(DATA_SET, DATA_LABELS)
id3.get_rules
# =>  if age_range=='<30' then marketing_target='Y'
  elsif age_range=='[30-50)' and city=='Chicago' then marketing_target='Y'
  elsif age_range=='[30-50)' and city=='New York' then marketing_target='N'
  elsif age_range=='[50-80]' then marketing_target='N'
  elsif age_range=='>80' then marketing_target='Y'
  else raise 'There was not enough information during training to do a proper induction for this data element' end
```

(So you basically will be able to take that last line insert it into your code.)

You need to choose enough already classified records to make DATA_SET and DATA_LABELS, and also you need to convert your hashes into arrays (which isn't that difficult – basically your hashes' keys are `DATA_LABELS`, and your hashes values are values of `DATA_SET` array).

When you add new `TYPE_CLASS`, just retry the 'teaching' and update your detection code.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting idea, will have a closer look.